# Is better create a single object Event instead of always create another?

Tags: actionscript-3, events

Usually when dispatching an Event (or custom Event) I use this:

```
function fireEvent():void {
    dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
}
```

Is better use a single object to dispatch an event every time? Can I do this?

```
var myEvent:Event = new Event(Event.COMPLETE);

function fireEvent():void {
    dispatchEvent(myEvent);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "better?"

Comment: One difference between your two examples is that the first one is *self-contained.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey, performance and memory optimization, for example... This Event is inside a Object that is created and killed many times...

Comment: In most decent OO languages, object creation is cheap, so unless you're trying to do this in a tight loop (which you probably shouldn't)...

Answer (score 3):

It would be a way better (eg create event pools) if it works. Unfortunately AS3 does some internal magic with event object during event flow which makes objects only one time usable (Sorry, by some reason I can't find proof quickly).

You can easily get confirmation by dispatching event second time, your listeners will not be triggered (may be it's true only for bubbling feature, not remember exactly), so you have to create a new instance of event object for every `dispatchEvent` call.

Comment: "internal magic" :P ... Yep, It's hard to believe in this "magic". My application run for days (uninterrupted) with the same memory range, but in a half hour the memory exceeds 1GB, and my app crashes... I'm thinking a way to maximum memory optimization...

Comment: just don't use events, use `as3signals` or own dispatch events system like starling did

Comment: Sad but true, dispatching an event object the second time leads to an undocumented behavior. Event objects in particular should be used like grenades, fire and forget, flash GC will eventually eat it. If your code processes an event, don't you dare taking a handle on that event! Process and leave no traces of the event object. Maybe you should check elsewhere for memory leaks.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't worth it even if pooling works, I presume. Creating event objects isn't expensive in astionscript, adding event listeners is. You'd better put this effort on managing listeners and handlers which could easily become the performance buttleneck.